# How can I blink background only instead of text

Tags: html, css

I just need to blink the background color only, not the Text. And I am unable to do that. I need your help.

```css
.blink{
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
            background-color: magenta;
        padding: 15px;  
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
.text{
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: cursive;
        color: white;
        animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
    }
@keyframes blink{
0%{opacity: 0;}
25%{opacity: .5;}
50%{opacity: 1;}
75%{opacity: .5;}
100%{opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="blink">
  <span class="text">blinking text</span></div>
```

Comment: just add the animation to the background container

Comment: @Sfili_81: OP must be mentioning about making the bg blink with the text intact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually added the animation property in the `text` class instead of the `blink`. Just shift it.

Also, if you're animating the `opacity` then the content inside the div will also fade. Considering that you only wish to animate the background, animate the `background-color` instead.

```css
.blink{
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: magenta;
        padding: 15px;  
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
    }
.text {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: cursive;
        color: black;
}
    
@keyframes blink {
  0%{background-color: magenta;}
  50%{background-color: white;}
  100%{background-color: magenta;}
}
```

```html
<div class="blink">
  <span class="text">blinking text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: And let me know How can I close this Question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```css
.blink{
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
            background-color: magenta;
        padding: 15px;  
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
.text{
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: cursive;
        color: white;
        animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
    }
@keyframes blink{
0%{opacity: 0;}
25%{opacity: .5;}
50%{opacity: 1;}
75%{opacity: .5;}
100%{opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="blink">
  <span class="text">blinking text</span></div>
```

Do this:

```css
.blink{
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
            background-color: magenta;
        padding: 15px;  
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
    }
.text{
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: cursive;
        color: white;
    }
@keyframes blink{
0%{opacity: 0;}
25%{opacity: .5;}
50%{opacity: 1;}
75%{opacity: .5;}
100%{opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="blink">
  <span class="text">blinking text</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help D-Waqas, But I want the text to be stable. Only Background to blink.